# sysLoader.getResource() problem in java

Tags: java, url, classloader

I am having following lines of code.

```
sysLoader = (URLClassLoader)Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
url = sysLoader.getResource("tempFile.txt");
```

It is giving an weird problem. If I run this from a path where there is no space in the path (Folder names) then it is running fine. But if the path contains any spaces (line "c:\New Foler...") then it is not working.

How to solve this?

EDIT: In more detail - I inspected the sysloader object.

> sysloader -> UCP -> path

Is having a path with character %20 instead of space

And therefore all the URLs are null.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Define "not working". Does it return `null`? Or does the returned `URL` not work in some context?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is known by Sun/Oracle, their advice is to use URI objects which will remove the %20 characters:

Instead of doing this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(url.getFile());
```

you can force any %-escaped characters to be decoded by first converting the URL to a URI, and then use the path component of the URI as the filename:

```
URI uri = new URI(url.toString());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(uri.getPath());
```

Comment: Here is the corresponding but report marked as "Won't fix": http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4466485 . This bug/feature still exists in Java 1.7 .

Comment: A shorter version without explicitly converting to string and back to URI would be:

  `URI uri = url.toURI();`
  `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(uri.getPath());`

Answer (score 13):

Use `URLDecoder.decode()` method to replace `%20` characters by spaces.

`String path = URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "UTF-8");`

Please also keep in mind that when resource is located in jar file you have to handle it different way. See it e.g. here: [How to access resources in jar where it can be present in multiple jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017762/how-to-access-resources-in-jar-where-it-can-be-present-in-multiple-jar)

Comment: Once you get the URL from getResource that is used, while passing the path in the file, we can use the method URLDecoder#decode. Something like this:

File file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(testFile.getFile(), "UTF-8"));

Here, testFile is a URL object.

I am adding a comment since even though I found the answer useful, I had to somehow think about how to use this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL of the file from string, when the path contains spaces, this is what worked for me:

```
File file = new File("/Users/work space/tempFile.txt");
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
```

According to Javadocs, `file.toURL()` is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURL--):

> This method does not automatically escape characters that are illegal in URLs. It is recommended that new code convert an abstract pathname into a URL by first converting it into a URI, via the toURI method, and then converting the URI into a URL via the URI.toURL method.

Hence used `file.toURI().toURL()`.

For Java 7+, this is approach can be taken instead:

```
URL url = Paths.get("/Users/work space/tempFile.txt").toURI().toURL());
```

*Note*: If the path begins with a `/` it is considered absolute else taken as a relative path.