# Why do I get a FileNotFoundException when ClassLoader.getSystemRessource(filename) gives a result?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception, filereader

My current application needs to get data from a file to initialize its attributes.
It needs to be stored in a file to enable modification to the user.

```
String strFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myFile.csv").getPath();
if(strFile==null)
        throw new Exception("File not find");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFile));
//Begin reading file process..
```

My problem is that `strFile` is not null but I have a *java.io.FileNotFoundException* when `br` is initialized, see the following stack:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\TH951S\My%20Documents\Eclipse\Workspace
                                 \My%20App\bin\myFile.csv 
                                 (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I checked that the file is in the designated path and everything seems correct.

Does anyone knows why this is happening? Or is there another way to get a file when the path is unknown?

Thanks for reading and more for answering,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my issue, one of those that make you feel stupid for not solving it sooner.

URLs are encoding spaces with value `%20` and Java do not replace the value by the space character when the `FileReader` is initialized. Therefore it is necessary to change `%20` by `" "`.

There is also another way of counturning it. It is also possible to initialize the `BufferedReader` with an `InputStreamReader` as following:

```
InputStream in=ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myFile.csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: I struggled with the same problem but the result *had* to be a `File` object (because I needed the size of the file).

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myFile.csv");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
System.out.println("Correct path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("Size of file: " + file.length());
```

The solution is inspired by [sysLoader.getResource() problem in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263560/sysloader-getresource-problem-in-java#13470643).

I was surprised that I had to go over so many classes but I didn't find a closer solution.