# java open file from classpath with a space character in it

Tags: java, file, web-applications

I have a webapp hosted in tomcat, and a jenkins build server.
I've previously read that the best way to read a file bundled with the jar, is to use the classpath rather than a hardcoded fullpath.

I usually see a variant of this to be the recommended way:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testfile.txt");
```

And this seems to work locally, but on the jenkins linux build server, which is setup to build in a directory containing a space, the getResourceAsStream() fail because internally it fails to lookup the file, since the path contains contains a space, which gets translated to %20.

Thus, I see only 2 possibilities, either:

- Everyone suggesting to use the getResourceAsStream() are wrong, and that a robust use which handles paths with spaces in it, need to do something more before calling getResourceAsStream()
- The getResourceAsStream contains a bug

I guess its really the first option, so then my question is, what's the most correct way to handle this?

Comment: try `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/testfile.txt").getFile();`
I prefer this over `getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: Same error. Though, the "This question may already have an answer here:" suggests that this is actually a bug, with a workaround by decoding the spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263560/sysloader-getresource-problem-in-java