# Exception in thread "main" when adding variable to a processBuilder

Tags: java

I have a ProcessBuilder that executes a shell script, it worked fine until I wanted to add an argument to the shell script from a variable.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at testOne.main(testOne.java:10)
```

---

*Line 9:*

```
String myarg = "testarg";
```

*Line 10 (the one that gives me the error):*

```
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c",
        testOne.class.getResource("/test.sh " + myarg).getPath());
```

I understand that I have have concatenated the /test.sh with the String and that it would be treated as filename now which is why it gives me the error. I am however clueless how I could solve it.

Comment: Please post the entire exception stacktrace message. It is *very* important and often will tell you *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: I addition to the stacktrace as Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggest, also show a [mcve].

Comment: This `testOne.class.getResource("/test.sh " + myarg).getPath()` does look fishy.

Comment: Added the entire exception stacktrace message.

Comment: What is line 10?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it works very well without the + myarg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: This question looks like a dupe of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404420/java-open-file-from-classpath-with-a-space-character-in-it?lq=1 (which itself has no own answer post, but links to another dupe).

Comment: @Tom it's not the same problem, I have checked.

Comment: *"it works very well without the + myarg"* - So get rid of the "+ myarg"!!  What you are doing in the working version is reading a resource containing a shell script.  When you add arguments, it fails because the "path" no longer matches any resource.  The `getResource(...)` returns `null` and you get an NPE because you don't check for `null`.  That line of code (as written) does not make sense.

Comment: Basically, you need to **understand** how "bash -c" works / what it does.  And figure out how to map that to what you are trying to do.  (The latter is not clear from the question ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c",
        testOne.class.getResource("/test.sh " + myarg).getPath());
```

This attempts to do too many thing in a single line. You should break it up into several pieces, assigning intermediate results to variables so that you can more easily debug it:

```
final URL bashScriptResource = testOne.class.getResource("/test.sh " + myarg);
final String bashScriptPath = bashScriptResource.getPath()
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c",
        bashScriptPath);
```

Now use a debugger or add `System.out.println()` calls to print the values of each variable. This will show you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in theory, nothing is wrong with the way I am doing it?

Comment: Since `new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c",
        testOne.class.getResource("/test.sh").getPath());` works fine.

Comment: @Lee-B The NullPointerException shows that there is something wrong with the way you are doing it. Take the idea that I show here a step further at look at the difference between `"/test.sh"` and `"/test.sh" + myarg`. Which of these result in a valid resource name?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, might me that is tired (so sorry, I really appreciate your help). All I want to do is to call a shell script with an argument. If I skip `+ myarg` it works. I do not know why adding `+ myarg` which is a String causes an error in Java. I tried to execute it in the shell and it works. `sh test.sh testargument`

Comment: @Lee-B Be careful separating what you want from what the code actually does. Look at this part: `testOne.class.getResource("/test.sh")` vs `testOne.class.getResource("/test.sh " + myarg)`. Neither of these execute a shell script. Instead they locate a resource, as the name suggests. The first tries to find a resource named `"/test.sh"`. The second tries to find a resource named `"/test.sh testarg"`. **A resource with this name does not exist.** Now when you attempt to execute the command with `ProcessBuilder`, you get an error because you are attempting to use a resource which doesn't exist.