# getResource(...).getFile() method throwing FileNotFoundException if name has white spaces

Tags: java, getresource

In the sample program below I am invoking the `getResource(...).getFile()` method twice, **in a Windows environment**.

In both cases the URI passed to the getResource method is a local file name, and the file exists.  The difference is that in the first case there is no whitespace in the name, but in the second case there is a whitespace in the name.  Things work well in the first case but in the second case I get the `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Sample code follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GetResourceExpt {
    static String fileUri1 = "./subfolder/data.txt";
    static String fileUri2 = "./sub folder/data.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName1 = GetResourceExpt.class.getResource(fileUri1).getFile();
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName1));
        System.out.println("Buffered Reader 1 instantiated!");
        br1.close();

        String fileName2 = GetResourceExpt.class.getResource(fileUri2).getFile();
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName2));
        System.out.println("Buffered Reader 2 instantiated!");
        br2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do NOT use file IO to read classpath resources. Use getResourceAsStream(): that gives you an InputStream that you can wrap in an InputStreamReader. Classpath resources are NOT files.

Comment: Using getResourceAsStream appears to be a good suggestion.  However, could you suggest what to do if you want to locate a resource and then open it for writing?

Comment: Classpath resources are read-only. If you want to write, use an actual file, not a classpath resource.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263560/sysloader-getresource-problem-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top