In java getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("") must return the root of my resources folder, right?
I have problems with Resources in Java with IntelliJ Idea 2024.1.1 (Community Edition). I use Gradle.
I'm on Windows 11.
Working on a Junit test, I must test the behavior of getResource() or getResourceAsStream(), which are returning null for the 2 methods.
My project structure:
/src
   /main
        /java
             /myclass.java
        /resources
                  /apps
                      /myapp.exe

/src
   /test
       /java
           /mytest.java
       /resources
                 /apps
                      /myapp.exe

The project is contained in something like I:/my workspace/my project
When I want to access to myapp.exe in mytest.java with getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("apps/myapp.exe") in a static method in myclass.java,
I get a nullpointerexception when I invoke getPath() on the resulting URL. Same with getResourceAsStream("apps/myapp.exe") when I invoke readAllBytes().
Whatever I do, these methods return null.
I have test with :
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()

but there, that's returning a completely broken path like:
file:///C:/Users/test/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.23.1/d2bb60570f5b3d7ffa8f8000118c9c07b86eca93/assertj-core-3.23.1.jar!/META-INF/versions/9/
I have added few lines in my build.gradle file:
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}

but IntelliJ Idea complains with a warning on the paths: Cannot instantiate interface 'SourceSet'
and don't work neither
Thx to help me resolve that

myclass.class.getResource("/apps/myapp.exe"); is what you want. But I would not recommend using the default package. Class names begin uppercase of course

Could be caused by spaces in path. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263560/sysloader-getresource-problem-in-java

Could also be that getClass is invoked on a generated class (by assertj?) rather than on your original class. Hence the class loader is custom loader that points to the assertj jar file. Try printing getClass().getName().

Thx goose that works now ! But can you explain me why getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("apps/myapp.exe") doesn't work anymore ?

ewramner : getClass().getName() prints the correct Test Class

Do not call getPath() and do not try to treat a resource as if it’s a file.  It is not a file.  If you want to read a resource, use the getResourceAsStream method.  Do not use files at all.

@VGR is right. getPath() only works when you are in development mode that all files sit in a directory eg: out/classes/myfile
Once you move to production, all file will be packed in a jar file, then there will be no path for your file any more.
